# Trying to create a responsive grid using html and css

Tags: html, css

For the two orange div boxes [in this code](http://codepen.io/roadtocode/pen/bVByWw) look a bit awkward. The right div's margin is slightly narrower than the left div's. How do I fix this?

`CSS`:

```
    html {font-size: 1em;}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.row,
.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.box {
        background-color: rgba(230, 126, 34,1);
        width: 37em;
        padding: 2em 0;
        margin-left: 2em;
        margin-top: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;


.container {
    background-color: slategrey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 72em;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of the `inline: block` try to change it to `float: left;`

```
div.box {
    background-color: rgba(230, 126, 34,1);
    width: 37em;
    padding: 2em 0;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
  //display: inline-block;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: I thought display: inline-block can replace float: left